# How to know if app updated (just before the update)?

Tags: android

In my app I have a background service that counts the screen on time.

If the app is updated I restart the service to continue counting,
but I need to do this only if service was running just before the update (due to the counts are invalid if system has kill the service before by any circunstance).

Is possible to know if the update of the app has been started but before the update ends?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save versionCode of your app in shared prferences and then compare with versionCode of your runing app. If it differs, then you can try to assume app was updated.

Comment: This don't solves the problem. The main problem is: In my my-app-updated receiver I need to know if the Service was running just before the update or not (due to it has crashed or killed by the system, by example).

Comment: then store timestamps of service in sharedpreferences as well

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but store timestamp for Service don't solves the problem, due to: 1) What timeout I need to set to assume that service is died by the system, 2) I need to awake the service even if no tasks to do and this isn't efficent. But I think Android isn't notyfing the app that is just to be updated :( Thanks again